# Selected item does not spin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu with icons and I am trying to make the fontawesome icon of the selected list rotate by adding the class .fa-spin. I have no idea why my code is not working eventhough I made the Index equal to the clicked item.

I appreciate some insights.

```
<ul>
<li><a class="menu-1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <span>1</span></a></li>
<li><a class="menu-1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span>2</span></a></li>
<li><a class="menu-1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-info"></i> <span>3</span></a></li>
<li><a class="menu-1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch"></i> <span>4</span></a></li>
<li><a class="menu-1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> <span>5</span></a></li>
<li><a class="menu-1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <span>6</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my Jquery code:

```
 $('nav ul li a').click(function(){
        $('nav ul li .fa').eq($(this).index()).addClass('fa-spin').siblings().removeClass('fa-spin');
});
```

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/u84z8guL/

Comment: Does the click function get executed? Your HTML does not show a <nav> element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your target elements are wrong - you need to add/remove the classes from the `anchor` elements

```js
$('nav ul li a').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('fa-spin').parent().siblings().find('.fa-spin').removeClass('fa-spin');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a class="menu-1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <span>1</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="menu-1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span>2</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="menu-1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-info"></i> <span>3</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="menu-1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch"></i> <span>4</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="menu-1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> <span>5</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="menu-1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <span>6</span></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Web Animation API

```
Element.animate();
```

Then you won't need to add classes and remove classes

Simplest reference: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/05/Web-Animations---element-animate-is-now-in-Chrome-36